# Express Static files on server not loading correctly but React Front end is loading correctly?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I have a ReactJS project with Node/Express serving my server. On my front end (React) is serving port 3312 and on my server it's serving port (5000). When I load my front end through port 3312, everything looks great and my react router routes works fine. (My api's work everything is great). However, when I try and serve static files and see if I get the same result through my server (port 5000) I only see the styles on my page. (I have a background color) I don't see any of the html whatsoever that the static files should be serving?

I get no errors in the console when I look at localhost:5000. However, my css styles are displaying on the page correctly (cause I have a background color set on my body). However, I cannot see any of my front end React displaying html code. I went inside my index.html file and put a simple test in the root div and it's displaying but I don't understand why my React code isn't displaying on my server.

I most likely think the problem is with the express static files not serving my images or React Router code. I should also note that I'm not using create-react-app I'm using webpack dev server react no cli.

Also, I'm not using create-react-app I'm using no cli for custom webpack.

Here is my code:

**(Node Server)**

```js
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const router = express.Router();

const app = express();
const port = 5000;

// Serve static files on server
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + "/../public"));

app.get("*", function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/../public/index.html"));
});

if (app.get("env") === "development") {
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
  });
} else {
  app.listen(port, "171.33.4.126", () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
  });
}
```

**routes.js**

```js
import React from "react";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import HomePage from "./components/homepage";
import AboutPage from "./components/aboutpage";
import Contactpage from "./components/contactpage";

export default (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Landingpage} />
        <Route exact path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
        <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contactpage} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

**index.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Routes from "./routes";

ReactDOM.render(<div>{Routes}</div>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link
      href="/public/assets/css/styles.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <title>Site</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Webpack Configuration Development**

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
// const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require("browser-sync-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 3312,
    proxy: {
      "/api": "http://localhost:5000"
    }
  },
  entry: ["babel-polyfill", __dirname + "/src/index.js"],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/public"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          query: {
            presets: ["react", "env", "stage-0"]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" },
          { loader: "sass-loader" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    //   template: "./public/index.html"
    // }),
    new BrowserSyncPlugin({
      host: "localhost",
      port: 3312,
      files: [
        "./public/*.html",
        "./public/assets/scss/*.scss",
        "./public/assets/variables/*.scss",
        "./public/assets/mixins/*.scss",
        "./public/assets/reset/*.scss"
      ],
      proxy: "http://localhost:3312/"
    })
  ]
};
```

**Here is a screenshot of my folder structure:**

[image]

Screenshot of network status in console:

[image]

Comment: what does `console.log(__dirname + "/../public"`)` says ? i bet the problem is with path

Comment: Uploaded a screenshot of my folder structure

Comment: logged console returns `C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\newrootportfolio\server/../public`

Comment: OK ...path to me seems right ...can you check network tab in web console to see what are you recieveing from server ?

Comment: I attached screenshot of network in localhost 5000 (server) localhost 3312 (client) works fine i can see the html css but on my server i can only see the css and not html

Comment: also try to refresh it with `ctrl+f5` bcs. it seems most of the things are loaded from cache :) or if u r using react starter app from service worker.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185226/discussion-between-maielo-and-jorden).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your react code is not showing up because `index.html` is not including it. Is `public/bundle.js` your transpiled react code? If so, add the following line to `index.html`, right after `<div id="root"></div>`:

```
<script src="/public/bundle.js"></script>
```

If not, then change the path pointed by src to the correct one.

You can see your css styles just fine because you are already including those in `index.html`.

**UPDATE:** a couple of points based on your webpack config:

- Change the port in which you are running webpack-dev-server to 3000. You will also have to change `BrowserSyncPlugin`'s proxy to `http://localhost:3000/`. You can then go to `localhost:3312` in your browser and requests will be proxied to the webpack-dev-server running on port 3000.
- Correct me if I'm wrong, but you have not posted your `index.html` in its entirety. I'm guessing you **already have** a line that looks like `<script src="/bundle.js"></script>` somewhere in that `.html` file -- based on your latest comment, it seems it is being added by `HtmlWebPackPlugin`. webpack-dev-server is serving `bundle.js` through `/`, the `publicPath` you've specified in webpack's `output` option. This works just fine as long as you access your site through `localhost:3312` or `localhost:3000`. However, your express.js server running on port 5000 has no idea webpack-dev-server is serving `bundle.js` at `/`; as a result of that, you end up seeing none of your react code when you go to `localhost:5000`. As for the styles, you are already serving them correctly through `/public/assets/css`, which the express.js server understands because you've specified that in this line: `app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + "/../public"))`. The solution is to change the line `<script src="/bundle.js"></script>` in your `.html` file to:

  ```
  <script src="http://localhost:3312/bundle.js"></script>
  ```

  Also, in webpack's output option, change the `publicPath` to `http://localhost:3312/`. Now, as long as you have webpack-dev-server running (with `BrowserSyncPlugin`), you can access 
  your site at `localhost:5000` and your `bundle.js` file should be 
  served just fine.

Try the following:

**Webpack Config**

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "/public"),
        historyApiFallback: true,
        port: 3000,
        proxy: {
            "/api": "http://localhost:5000"
        }
    },
    entry: ["babel-polyfill", __dirname + "/src/index.js"],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "/public"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "http://localhost:3312/"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    query: {
                        presets: ["react", "env", "stage-0"]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "css-loader" },
                    { loader: "sass-loader" }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new BrowserSyncPlugin({
            host: "localhost",
            port: 3312,
            files: [
                "./public/*.html",
                "./public/assets/scss/*.scss",
                "./public/assets/variables/*.scss",
                "./public/assets/mixins/*.scss",
                "./public/assets/reset/*.scss"
            ],
            proxy: "http://localhost:3000/"
        })
    ]
};
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <link
            href="/assets/css/styles.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            type="text/css"
        />
        <title>Site</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="http://localhost:3312/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For my custom webpack configuration, I'm using webpack plugin to include the index.html file which includes the bundle.js i believe?

Comment: @Jorden could you add your webpack config to your question? I assume you are referring to `HtmlWebpackPlugin`. If that's the case, and if `index.html` is the output, it is clearly not including `bundle.js`. Try adding it manually; it should work then.

Comment: You can also tell by looking at the screenshot you posted; there is no request to the `/public/bundle.js` asset, that means it is not present in the html your express backend sends to the client.

Comment: But whats odd is when I preview source in the browser, the /bundle.js is included but I cannot see it in my file. I'll post a screenshot of my file though.

Comment: @Jorden I'm not sure what you meant in your last sentence, but I've updated my answer. I hope that helps.

Comment: For my webpack configuration, I'm using html-webpack-plugin which injects the bundle.js into my index.html file. When I open up my index.html file, I don't see the bundle.js in there However, when I go to localhost:3312 and view source, the bundle.js is included in the source code. In the source code it's including it via /bundle.js not /public/bundle.js

Comment: Also, I did what you told me and commented out html webpack plugin in my webpack configuration, and manually included it into the index.html file. Now when I go to localhost:5000 everything works fine but when I go back to localhost:3312 it says `cannot get /`

Comment: @Jorden I didn't say you should comment out `HtmlWebpackPlugin`. Don't do that. Enable it back and try following my updated answer once again. I believe that should get things working for you.

Comment: I'm so close lol. I think know what the problem is though. HtmlWebpackPlugin is working fine on localhost:3312 (front end) but on localhost:5000 (server) it's not serving the bundle.js file. I can't write bundle.js manually in my index.html file because HtmlWebpackPlugin is already injecting `bundle.js` in memory and not in the script. My express server has no way to read the injected bundle.js in the index.html file. Thats why it works fine on my client but on my server it has no idea. I believe that's the problem right? You're the closest answer I got so far.

Comment: @Jorden Yeah. Check out my updated answer. I ended up removing `HtmlWebpackPlugin` after all. I think it should work.

Comment: I did remove HtmlWebpack Plugin and I got what you told me. it goes in reverse this time. My server is displaying the page just fine but suddenly localhost 3312 my client is now reading `cannot get /`. What I'm basically trying to do is making sure both my front end and server display the page fine but not both are working only one is.

Comment: Actually when I go to that url, the styles load on the page. However, my react view isn't showing. on the server everything loads fine but on my client when I go to that url only the styles show. I checked the network console on that url and the bundle.js reports 304

Comment: @Jorden Okay, I think I've found the missing piece. Webpack's devServer doesn't know where to find the `index.html` that's to be served when you visit localhost:3312. To solve that, you need to add the `contentBase` option to `devServer`. It should point to wherever the `index.html` file lives. I've updated my answer (the devServer part).

Comment: Okay that actually fixed it! The client is now rendering the page fine but on the server the styles aren't loading but the react code is showing! I think i need to tweek how it's rendering the styles cause when I look in my console its throwing errors saying it can't files all my js/css files let me tweak some stuff. I'll get back to you thank you so much

Comment: @Jorden Since we've changed `contentBase`, you will have to change the css' `href` in the html to `/assets/css/styles.css` (no more public at the beginning). You can make that work with the server as well if you use `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/../public"))`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been stuck on this for months. I can finally deploy my app to production!! I didn't want to rely on create-react-app to do all the configuration for me I wanted to learn how to set up everything myself. It's better that way. Thank you for helping solve my problem. I'm awarding you the answer

Comment: @Jorden No problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Oh sorry, it looks like the problem is in index.js. Change `{Routes}` to `<Routes />`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Routes from "./routes";

ReactDOM.render(<div><Routes/></div>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

You have another problem in routes.js. Export a component like

```
import React from "react";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import HomePage from "./components/homepage";
import AboutPage from "./components/aboutpage";
import Contactpage from "./components/contactpage";

// make this a component
export default ()=>(
  <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Landingpage} />
        <Route exact path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
        <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contactpage} />
      </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```

Comment: @Jorden Is it fixed? The problem is that you are not rendering the Routes component hence nothing will show up

Comment: No its the same effect. I checked the front end and the console returned: `Element type is invalid expected a string (for built in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got object.`

Comment: I have seen another problem in your React code let me update the answer

Comment: What you are exporting in routes.js isn't a component. Thats why you are receiving that error

Comment: The expresss side is ok. Looks like you are having a couple of problems with React

Comment: What is chat rq?